# Redisgraph in Azure

Tags: azure, redis-cluster, redisgraph

Is Redisgraph available in Azure through the Market place?

We only see Redis Cache service in Azure Market place.

We wanted to deploy RedisGraph using the Azure arm template, is it possible?

Comment: It is not available from the marketplace today but you can get a RedisGraph managed service from Redis Labs Cloud: https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise-cloud